Finding a multivariate function that satisfies constraints on the log scale
I am need of a multivariate function $$f(x, y)$$ that satisfies the following properties:
$$f(0, 0) = 0$$
$$f(0, 1) = 1$$
$$f(1, 0) = 1$$
$$f(1, 1) = 1$$
when also log transformed; that is log($f(x, y)$).
The function $$f(x, y) = \frac{x + y}{1 + \textrm{min}(x, y)}$$ works on the untransformed scale (which is also needed), but it fails on the log scale for $f(0, 0)$, since log(0) is undefined.
So far, I've just been using a guess-and-check approach, but that seems very inefficient.
Any $f(x, y)$ should satisfy both the untransformed and the log transformed case.
Any ideas on how to approach this? If there is no such function, does there exist a transformation other than log that also satisfies constraints on the untransformed scale?

This is unclear. What do you mean by "log transformed"? $\log(f(x,y))$? or maybe $\log f(\log x, \log y)$? or possibly $\log f(e^x, e^y)$ (this is what gets plotted in a log-log graph)? Maybe not the natural logarithm? Also, do you want both $f$ and its log-transformed version to satisfy these values? Or just the log-transformed version? If both are to satisfy the values, and you are talking about $\log f(x,y)$, then give up. No such function can exist.

@PaulSinclair I've clarified my post. My case is log($f(x, y)$) but is there another transformation that works?
